# Can you call from VB.Net code the ability to drop and create a stored procedure script?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server, then I create the drop/create script and am trying to see if I can run that script from within VB.net.  Is that possible?  If so how.  I have looked for the answer and am unable to find it so I am not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: You could use the [Drop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.storedprocedure.drop.aspx)  and [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.storedprocedure.create.aspx) methods on the [StoredProcedure class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredProcedure.aspx) from the  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo  namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx)

Comment: In the Examples section of the Create and Drop method there's a link to page in docs titled [Creating, Altering, and Removing Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162190.aspx) that shows you how

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlConnection and SqlCommand, in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.

Specifically:
[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that and am getting the error "Incorrect Syntax near GO"

Comment: I changed the "Go's" to semicolons and now I dont get the errors but it only runs the "DROP PROCEDURE" portion of it.

Comment: "GO" is for Microsoft's tooling, such as SQL Server Management Studio. Just run 2 SqlCommands, one for each batch. Alternatively, post your code and we can give better advice.